# delete[] allocated memory in destructor throw error

Tags: c++

I can't call `delete[]` because it's throwing an error in the destructor. Code with comments below.

[image: Screenshot of debug info]

```
class Packet
{
public:
    Packet(char* data, int len, ConnectionData* connectiont, int cmdtype) : _len(len), _connection(connectiont), _cmdtype(cmdtype)
    {
        _data = new char[len]; //allocate memory
        memcpy(_data, data, len); //copy to allocated memory
    }

    Packet() = default;

    ~Packet()
    {
        delete[] _data; /*error here*/
    }

private:
    char* _data;
    int _len, _cmdtype = 0;
    ConnectionData* _connection;
};


//Where create object of class and call constuctor.
char* _tempbuffer = new char[_templen];     
memcpy(_tempbuffer, _ph.getBuffer() + _temppos, _templen);

_separatedPackets.push_back(Packet(_tempbuffer, _templen, connection, _cmdtype));
```

Comment: did you instantiate `Packet` with the default constructor?

Comment: What's the error ? Can you also add the code where you use this class (incl. construction and destruction) ?

Comment: @fdan , no. Object instanted by using custom constructor

Comment: There is probably a bug in the code you didn't show here. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: My 2 cents that you copy constructed or copy assigned a `Packet` and therefore created 2 objects that pointed to the same `char* _data`, which was deleted twice.
Maybe read about the rule of 5 in C++.
Note that this is only my suspicion, you should really post your concrete error to let us reason about it.

Comment: You should at the very least initialize _data: `char* _data{ nullptr };` in the class declaration! That way, if any of the other commentators' suggestions are correct, the attempt to `delete[]` it will not throw.

Comment: @Dmirty Your code in the edited question is still not a [mcve]. Gobra's answer below is probably correct, but without seeing your code we can't be sure.

Comment: you're probably getting a double-free because you don't define copy or move operations, read up on rule of 0,3,5

Comment: @kmdreko , so I getting error just when calling desructor when destroyed std::vector of objects. How can i fix this?

Comment: @Dmirty The problem is that when calling `std::vector::push_back` you pass it a temporary object which will be copied into the vector, using the implicitly declared copy constructor of your class. Define your copy constructor to correctly handle the copying of the `_data` field.

Comment: @Dmirty you need a copy constructor. If you use the default constructor, the `data` pointer is copied to the new object and thus both the object and the object's copy point to the same data in memory. This is basic C++  knowledge. Read about the [rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 3):

I'll summarize what others have mentioned:

1. You have default constructor with no initializer for `_data` property, it can point on anything, thus leading to crash while attempting to delete memory that was never allocated.
2. You have (by default) [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) enabled as well as [operator =](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment). That means you might have assigned one `Packet` instance to another somewhere and having few `_data` pointers holding the same address leading to over-delete once those packets are freed.

Obvious solution to initialize `_data` properly and manage copying or remove default constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator altogether (see the link on cpp reference).

Also, I'd recommend to use `std::vector<uint8_t>` to store data, use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` to hold pointers to objects - and you will not have those issues at all.

Edit: Regarding your updated code - `vector.push_back()` will make a copy of the `Packet` object, temporary object will be deleted after that deleting data as well. Next `Packet` destructor (on the copy) will over-delete memory.

Comment: I edited post and added more info